# Is it good or bad practice to test interfaces from container?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Help me please clarify the following design approach:
In our unit tests projects we are using `UnityContainer`. In the beginning of every test we are resolving an object to test via that Container like that:

```
IObjectToTest objectToTest = container.Resolve<IObjectToTest>();
```

In Unity configuration we configured the concrete implementation of `IObjectToTest`. 
And in test we testing this interface `IObjectToTest` objectToTest despite of concrete instance of the object.

The question is: what is pros and cons of this approach? Why cannot we just instantiate new `ObjectToTest` (concrete implementation) and test it? Why do we use Unity and interface?

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's nothing strange at all in this approach, actually it is more common than what you think. When you want to write testable code you will find yourself using a lot of dependency injection.

The benefits are obvious, you can easily swap concrete implementations without having to re-write all your tests, you can stub out implementations and mock them to test only what you're interested in testing. So, in simple words, you're NOT ONLY testing interfaces you're testing (and injecting) concrete implementations through your container. This is a very common approach and it is a good practice to always use dependency injection through interfaces.

Comment: I do not know. What if in test I verify that method calls another methods. In current approach all implementation should call this methods too. And if all implementations do the same what for do we really need these implementation?

Comment: I just don't figure out what kind of different implementations we can have? It seems that implementations must be exactly the same. If they are different that this difference it should be tested.

Comment: I had this misconception about interfaces early on also. An interface can serve the purpose you're referring to. It can be used to abstract the implementation from the caller when the implementation differs greatly in each concrete implementation.  This fact is also why it is still a great idea even if there is only one implementor of that interface.  You can swap out concrete implementations for test fakes as Leo mentions above, and my example shows below.

Comment: @name1ess0ne then you're not unit testing because you shouldn't care about what the concrete object is doing within its implementation, whether it calls one, two or 3 methods is not the concern of the unit test...when you're unit testing you separate/isolate the complexities of a larger object to...for example, check the state of the return value or make sure it doesn't throw exceptions, or making sure it does throw an exception under certain circumstances, etc

Answer (score 1):

Testing against the interface is generally considered a best practice.  The reason you test against the interface and not the concrete implementation is to create actual "unit" tests and not integration tests.

If you test against concrete implementations of dependent classes with the object under test, then you are not truly testing the unit, but rather the integration.  Ultimately the integration is important in the production code, but if the individual units are tested thoroughly and properly, you have nothing to fear.

Typically you would still write an integration tests that validates the full connected implementation, but there would be more focus on the unit tests.

in the examples below, we test the behavior of `IObjectUnderTest` without regard to the implementation of `IBusinessLogicObject`.  We verify the collaboration between the two objects by mocking the dependency using the [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) framework. By doing this, we verify simply that the necessary collaboration occurred between the two objects, and do not concern ourselves with the innards of IBusinessLogicObject.  Those concerns are better suited for the unit tests we would write for IBusinessLogicObject.

Test Example

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
Mock<IBusinessLogicObject> businessLogicObject = new Mock<IBusinessLogicObject>();
container.RegisterInstance<IBusinessLogicObject>(businessLogicObject.Object);
businessLogicObject
    .Setup(bl => bl.SomeMethod("some-stub-parameter"))
    .Returns("some expected value")

IObjectUnderTest subject = container.Resolve<IObjectUnderTest>();
var emptyResult = subject.MethodToBeTested("some-stub-parameter", "another-value");
Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, emptyResult);
var result = subject.MethodToBeTested("some-stub-parameter", "businessLogic");
Assert.AreEqual("some expected value", result);
```

Implementation example

```
public ObjectUnderTest : IObjectUnderTest
{
    private readonly IBusinessLogicObject businessLogicObject;
    public ObjectUnderTest(IBusinessLogicObject businessLogicObject)
    {
        businessLogicObject = businessLogicObject;
    }
    string IObjectUnderTest.MethodToBeTested(string businessLogicParam, string someOtherParam)
    {
        if ( someOtherParam == "businessLogic")
        {
            return businessLogicObject.SomeMethod(businessLogicParam);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please confirm your first statement with some links? why it is considered as a best practice? I'm not saying it is wrong, but I was always under impression that "unit test" means to test ONE SINGLE unit of IMPLEMENTED code. Testing "Interface+Implementation" bundle is more like an integration test. Moreover in your example you use UnityContainer, so indirectly you are also testing unity configuration. It would be great if you help me understand your point.

Comment: My test doesn't actually test Unity configuration.  My test registers specific mocked dependencies for resolution in `ObjectUnderTest`. If I did not mock those dependencies and register them explicitly, then yes I would be testing Unity configuration.  By mocking the dependencies of `ObjectUnderTest`, I am relying on their interface ,not their implementation.  You can't test an unimplemented interface.  In my test we are testing the concrete implementation of `ObjectUnderTest`.  This object implements an interface so that when `ObjectUnderTest` is a dependency, it can be mocked.

Comment: By definition, if you don't mock dependencies, the test will be integration, and not unit.  If the only production code that runs during your test is written inside the object under test, then it would be considered a unit test. See this thread for other examples http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/65477/why-is-it-important-that-a-unit-test-not-test-dependencies